# MongoDB: latest of multiple causally consistent sessions

Tags: mongodb, consistency

I'm using MongoDB causal consistency feature and trying to "merge" multiple causal sessions into one, which should be able to read writes from all initial sessions.

Seems like it should be possible to just pick max cluster/operation time from each session. But I could not understand the difference between these timestamps. Why there are two of them at all?

Is it really possible to combine multiple sessions like that?

Comment: No it's not possible. The point of a causally consistent session is to ensure that within that session, operation causality is guaranteed. "Merging" different sessions would remove this guarantee. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#client-sessions-and-causal-consistency-guarantees for more details.

Comment: Here's another post that describe causal consistency in MongoDB in greater detail: https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/ryp0ohr2w9pvv0fks88kq6qkz9k9p3